# Смещение курсора у input-элементов модального окна в iOS 11

Tags: ios, вёрстка, iphone, safari, ios11

Проблема появилась в iOS 11 (встречается во всех браузерах на этой ОС, включая Safari и Chrome). При открытии модального окна с input-элементами происходит смещение курсора выше или ниже области ввода текста (в некоторых случаях он может вообще уйти в сторону).

[image]

Как позже выяснил, это общий баг для всех устройств по iOS:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как вы ее решали?

Судя по отзывам на странице с багом проблема актуальна для iOS 11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3 и пока еще не решена разработчиками Apple (причем некоторые фиксы не работают в версиях 11.2 и 11.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас существует ряд фиксов, которые могут немного исправить ситуацию, но полноценного рабочего варианта до сих пор нет.

Например, такие способы предлагают здесь:
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8

**Возможные пути решения:**

**1. Задание позиции fixed у тега body**

При открытии модального окна добавляем стиль `position: fixed` для тега `body`, а после закрытия - удаляем. Однако, если модальное окно было открыто не в самом верху страницы, при его закрытии страница смещается вверх (можно поправить сохраняя при открытии и выставляя при закрытии позицию скроллинга).

Минусы:

- При закрытии модального окна появляется адресная строка и панель с закладками, что раздражает (вызвано из-за JS-позиционирования скролла).
- Сильные смещения убираются, но на input-элементах в нижней части модального окна все равно сохраняется небольшое смещение курсора (работать в этом случае пользователь может, но визуально выглядит не самым приятным образом).

**2. Перевод отображения модального окна с position: fixed на absolute.**

Модальному окну присваивается свойство `position: absolute`, размеры и смещение рассчитываются при его создании. Этот подход в корне устраняет проблему со смещением курсора, но имеет ряд неприятных артефактов.

Минусы:

- На смартфоне с iOS при открытии клавиатуры происходит сдвиг экрана по центру input-элемента, из-за чего отключается блокировка скролла и темный overlay не полностью покрывает область экрана.
- На ряде мобильных устройств сохраняется нижняя яркая полоска не покрытая темным overlay даже при правильных расчетах высоты экрана.

**3. Перевести все модальные окна на отдельные страницы**

Этот подход более радикальный, т.к. подразумевает полностью переписывание для iOS всего кода, который используется в модальных окнах, но я его вижу наиболее полно устраняющим проблему.

Минусы:

- Надо полностью убирать модальные окна на iOS 11 и переводить их содержимое в обычную страницу

Answer (score 2):

Вчера обновился до ios 11.3, проблемы с курсором у меня больше нет, до этого она была на прошлых версиях ios 11.

Comment: это радует, что все-таки исправили баг. проблема только в том, что обновляются не все))

Comment: Думаю, те кто обновился до ios 11, скорее всего будут обновлять ее до последней версии, т.к. производительность падать, как при обновлении до номерной версии не будет, но баги будут фиксить, а вот на 12 перейдут далеко не все.